# What's a word that means *something that facilitates something else*?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word that means *something that facilitates something else*?

A word meaning to facilitate change; allow it to happen; help it come to life. Almost as if serving as an open doorway to an idea or the creation of a new thing because of what another thing did to it, or allowed it to do.

I seem to remember associating this mystery word with energy conductivity or chemistry. Synonyms might include facilitator, conductor, precipitate...

Comment: I think this is General Reference rather than Not Constructive. You've already said you want to facilitate it. Obviously you want to [act as a **facilitator**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22act+as+a+facilitator%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Strictly speaking, an "idea" is normally *realised*, not *facilitated*, but not many people would use [act as a realiser](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22act+as+a+realiser%22&oq=%22act+as+a+realiser%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.2037j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Are you thinking of "conduit"?

Comment: @MετάEd How would you suggest *conduit* which is not a 'facilitator/ catalyst'? *Conduit* even has negative connotations.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Why is this question closed?

Comment: @Pacerier: For some reason the question text has been extensively edited since I made my comment. I still think if OP had simply wanted an "agent noun" for "one who facilitates" that would be OT GenRef (it appears he really wanted us to jog his memory for ***catalyst***, but that could easily be addressed by googling ***synonym facilitator*** and checking [the alternatives listed here](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/facilitator), for example). But as to why it was *actually* closed - you'll note that I personally never cast a closevote. I just made a comment which I still stand by.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could be a **catalyst** for the idea, a term that comes from chemistry meaning (according to [MWD](http://i.word.com/idictionary/catalyst))

> 1 : a substance that enables a chemical reaction to proceed at a usually faster rate or under different conditions (as at a lower temperature) than otherwise possible
>
> 2 : an agent that provokes or speeds significant change or action

Comment: Thank you so much. I love that word, and for some reason it just vanished from my brain a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to emphasize your enthusiasm you could **champion** that idea

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the word you are looking for is 'expeditor', or expediter.

According to the Wikipedia article,

> An expeditor is someone who facilitates a process. It is a position or role found within project management, construction, purchasing and production control.

Answer (score 0):

The word that occurs to me is **advocate**.